# Insert into mysql and php using array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have part of the code below:

```
while($array = $result->fetch_assoc() ){


    $second_query = "INSERT INTO".TBL_USERSDONTPAY."VALUES ($array[\"username\"], $array[\"password\"], '0',$array[\"userid|\"], )";

$second_result = $database->query($second_query);

}
```

The query doesn't seem to work. Any clues? I think it's a problem with the quotes or something. How can actually pass array elements?

here is my whole code i want to move one row to another table

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$subuser'"; 
          $result = $database->query($q); 

          if($result && $result->num_rows == 1){
              while($array = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                  $second_query = "INSERT INTO" . TBL_USERSDONTPAY . "VALUES ('" . $array['username'] . "', '" . $array['password'] . "', '0', '" . $array['userid'] ."')";


                  $second_result = $database->query($second_query);
                  if($second_result){
                      // it worked!
                      $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$subuser'";
                      $database->query($q);
                  }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Looks like you need some spaces:
... "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERSDONTPAY." VALUES ...

Comment: you should update your question to reflect that the query is working now, but does not insert a row actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues with your query code

1. escaping of the array indexes in your string:

   you can either end the string and concatenate the parts together:

   ```
   $second_query = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_USERSDONTPAY . 
                   " VALUES ('" . $array['username'] . "', '" . $array['password'] . "', '0', '" . $array['userid'] . "')";
   ```

   or use the `{$var}` syntax:

   ```
   $second_query = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_USERSDONTPAY . 
                   " VALUES ('{$array['username']}', '{$array['password']}', '0', '{$array['userid']}')";
   ```
2. missing spaces (see example code above .. you were missing the spaces before and after the table name)
3. missing field names. your query may work without if you specify all fields in the right order, but will fail misteriously when you alter the table later (e.g. add a field to the table)

   ```
   $second_query = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_USERSDONTPAY . 
                   " (username, password, foo, user_id)".
                   " VALUES ('{$array['username']}', '{$array['password']}', '0', '{$array['userid']}')";
   ```

   please note you should actually insert the correct field names in the second line of my example above. You can find more information on this in the [MySQL docs for INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: after making some expiriments i found out that it cant pass that line of code if($result && $result->num_rows == 1) so whats problem with that?

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens possibly there is more than one row returned with the same username - you check for `num_rows == 1`. Did you make sure that usernames are `UNIQUE` using a unique key in the table definition? check your data.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your query is *screaming* for SQL injection, you may examine the result of calling [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after calling `mysql_query(...)` (or `$database->query(...)` in your case) to see what's going wrong.

Comment: sorry it's the first time i'm coding a php login system what is the best way to do it to prevent mysql injection?

Comment: If this is the first time you're using php (is it?) I'd suggest that you do it right from the start by using [PDO](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements. This is *far better* than using `mysql_query` and having to escape everything yourself. Unfortunately the latter is how most people start (minus the escaping...). Google is your friend here (as is Stackoverflow, try searching first, the truth is out here :)

Comment: Also, better save the password encrypted, e.g. create an extra column `salt` (varchar(40)), and extend the length of the `password` column to varchar(40). Then for each new user, generate a salt using e.g. `$salt = sha1(microtime(true))`, encrypt the password using `sha1($password . $salt)` and save both. To check the password you can use lookup the user record, use the salt and the entered password, re-apply the same logic to those and check if this matches the `password` field in the db. There you go.

Comment: thanks bart no it's not the first time using php. i was coding some cli scripts and not something big!

Answer (score 3):

You need to clean that query up and remove the final comma.

```
$second_query = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_USERSDONTPAY . " VALUES ('" . $array['username'] . "', '" . $array['password'] . "', '0', '" . $array['userid'] . "')";
```

Comment: ok now it's ok the query works but doesn't changes my usersdontpay table